# How to load RewardedAd?

Tags: android, admob

**Hello!**

I want to get reward in my app using RewardedAd (admob). I followed official admob video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmrTF0hLsIk). This is my code:

```
public void loadAd(){

    this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
    RewardedAdLoadCallback callback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(i);

            Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardedAdFailedToLoad");
        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
            super.onRewardedAdLoaded();

            Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardedTagLoaded");
        }
    };
    this.rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(), callback);
}



public void showAd(){

    if (this.rewardedAd.isLoaded()){

        RewardedAdCallback callback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {

                Log.i(TAG, "OnUserEarnedReward");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                super.onRewardedAdOpened();

                Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardAdOpened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                super.onRewardedAdClosed();

                Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardAdClosed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int i) {
                super.onRewardedAdFailedToShow(i);

                Log.i(TAG, "OnRewardedAdFailedToShow");
            }
        };
        this.rewardedAd.show(this, callback);

    } else {

        Log.i(TAG, "Ad not loaded.");
    }
}
```

But my ad isn't loading. When I try to showAd(), logcat shows me this message:

```
01-17 19:27:00.144 27830-27830/com.example.quiz E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.

01-17 19:27:08.968 27830-27830/com.example.quiz I/RewardActivity: Ad not loaded.

01-17 19:27:02.256 27830-27830/com.example.quiz I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
```

I'm using Google's test IDs. What's wrong with my code? Why does my ads not loading? What can I do?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same tutorial and i checked your code it seems to be right this is my code just in case you want to double check! And after you press the load button try to press the show button a couple times because sometimes the ad take some time to load. And don't forget to set the buttons onClick function from the activity_main.xml.

This is the MainActivity:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void showAd(View view) {

        if(this.rewardedAd.isLoaded()){

            RewardedAdCallback callback = new RewardedAdCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                   Log.i("MainActivity","Got Reward");
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdOpened() {
                    super.onRewardedAdOpened();
                        Log.i("MainActivity","Opened");
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdClosed() {
                    super.onRewardedAdClosed();
                    Log.i("MainActivity","Closed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onRewardedAdFailedToShow(int i) {
                    super.onRewardedAdFailedToShow(i);
                    Log.i("MainActivity","Failed to show");
                }
            };
            this.rewardedAd.show(this,callback);

        }
        else{
            Log.i("MainActivity","Not Loaded");
        }
    }

    public void loadAd(View view) {

        this.rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");
        RewardedAdLoadCallback callback = new RewardedAdLoadCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onRewardedAdFailedToLoad(i);
                Log.i("MainActivity","Failed");
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedAdLoaded() {
                super.onRewardedAdLoaded();
                Log.i("MainActivity","Loaded");
            }
        };

        this.rewardedAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build(),callback);
    }
}
```

This is the Android Manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jalaleddine.abdelbasset.admobtest"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Thx Abdelbasset Jalaleddine

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution, virtual device version must be android 8.0 or higher bc it needs to have internet connection!